# Basic Message v/s SMTP message in cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp, smtp

I was wondering what is the difference between sending a [basic message](http://book.cakephp.org/view/269/Sending-a-basic-message) and [message using SMTP](http://book.cakephp.org/view/481/Sending-A-Message-Using-SMTP) in cakephp

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic message just uses PHP's [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to drop off the message to whatever mail handler is configured locally. On your local computer this usually means that the machine will try to deliver the message itself, which often results in it either being rejected or going straight into the spam folder of the receiver. On a properly set up hosted server this is usually not a problem though.

Delivering via SMTP lets you specify an SMTP server that will take over the message delivery for you. A well known and established SMTP server has much better chances of delivering a message to the intended recipient.